# Getting a new second textfield on change of anything on first field and getting third textfield only when anything changed on second textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this feature where the first textfield is showed by default. As soon as the user writes on the first textfield, we show them a second textfield and when user writes on third textfield, we show them a fourth textfield.

Here is the code that wrote but the problem is even when user writes anything on first textfield, I get second, third, forth etc textfields which is not at all good.

```
renderBlock = () => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.counter; i++) {
    arr.push(
      <FormItem>
        <TextField
          autoCorrect={false}
          label="Enter the option"
          onChangeText={this.updateOptions}
          name="option"
        />
      </FormItem>
    );
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The state i am maintaining

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    counter: 1
  };
}
```

I am just rendering the renderblock inside my render.

Comment: Show your `render()` method

Comment: You also have to show us your `updateOptions` since this is where the logic is going to be. You are asking quite a complicated question, I think it is better if you create a reproducible example and give us a link to a codepen. Please also specify if there is a particular bug you are dealing with or if you are just asking for the complete solution and have made no attempt to complete this yourself.